# shellinabox - How can I restrict access to certain users only?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, shell, remote-access

I've got a Ubuntu 14.04 machine which I've set up with `shellinabox`.

Now I would like to restrict access to `shellinabox` to only a certain user account. Nobody else should be able to log in with it. All other SSH-connections should be unaffected.

I've tried adding `AllowUsers` to `sshd_config` but that then restricts all SSH connections not just `shellinabox`.

Is there any way of doing that?

Edit:

For now I've set up an Apache reverse proxy with base authentication in front of `shellinabox` so I basically only allow one user through to the actual console.
Not ideal but workable for now.

Answer (score 1):

That should work usually. Did you write the username of the actual user after the AllowUsers tag?

Your sshd_config should look like this:

```
[...]
AllowUsers shellinabox
[...]
```

It means only the usernames behind that tag are allowed. Maybe you misunderstood the meaning of the tag. Try it again and dont forget to restart the ssh-Deamon (sshd restart).

EDIT:
After reading your problem twice I don't understand your actual goal. :) You want to restrict shellinabox and allow all others?

If so try it with the tag DenyUsers:

```
[...]
DenyUsers shellinabox
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Have just updated my question. Hope it's more clear now?